# automation testing of window based application

Tags: automated-tests

I have a window based application (c++) with list of log files;
 **number of logs would vary.**

When each of the listed log file(**each has different name)** is double clicked a window pops up.The success criteria here is the successful opening of window on double click - this is to verified for each log file

How can I automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a program like Winium. It is a Selenium-based tool for testing windows apps. For further info, check this out: https://github.com/2gis/Winium

An alternative could be an Robotic Process Automation tool (RPA) like UIPath. It is not a testing tool per se, but it can be used as such and get your job done. There is a free community version available. Here's a link: https://www.uipath.com/